# How to reauthorize a user in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

## Environment

- Firebase JavaScript SDK v8

---

## Question

How can I re-authorize an already-logged-in user with their password? What I want to do is like below:

```js
const password = "some-password"
firebase.reAuthorizeUser(password)
  .then(() => console.log("ok"))
  .catch(() => console.log("ng"))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`reauthenticateWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithcredential) method.

```js
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

// TODO(you): prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
const credential = promptForCredentials();

user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then(() => {
  // User re-authenticated.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error ocurred
  // ...
});
```

Checkout [reauthenticate a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a switch case based on providerId, below should help.

```
    user.providerData.forEach((profile) => {
      switch (profile.providerId) {
        case 'google.com':
          user
            .reauthenticateWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
            .then((UserCredential) => {
             **//reauthenticated successfully!**
              })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
             **//Something is wrong**
            })
          break
        case 'password':
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-case-declarations
          const credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
            user.email,
            userPassword
          )
          user
            .reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials)
            .then(() => {
             **//reauthenticated successfully!**
                },
              }) 
            })
            .catch(() => {
              **//Something is wrong**
            })
          break
     })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 1 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.

Comment: @MDZand The accepted answer is actually copy/paste from documentation, doesn't provide implementation steps. I tried it and it didn't work so I wrote my own and pasted it here for future reference. The promptForCredentials() function is not a firebase function but coded, I provided extended answer with what should go in that function basically.

Answer (score 1):

SDK v9

```
import {getAuth, reauthenticateWithCredential, EmailAuthProvider} from "firebase/auth";

  const reauthenticate = async () => {
    try {
        const auth = getAuth();
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        const credential = await EmailAuthProvider.credential(
            email,
            password
        );
        await reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential);
        return true
    } catch (e) {
        return null
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

const credential = promptForCredentials();

this is giving me error

cant find variable: promptForCredentials.

Comment: `promptForCredentials()` is not a predefined function. You must write your own code to get [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth#usercredential).